# Where is the defaultDispatche instanced by Hilt?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-hilt

The Code A is from the end branch of the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

The project use *Hilt* to implement dependency injection.

I searched the the whole project, I find only the code  `annotation class DefaultDispatcher`, but I can't understand what the code mean.

Where is the defaultDispatche instanced by Hilt ?

**Code A**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    @DefaultDispatcher private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : ViewModel() {
   ...
}



@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun CraneHomeContent(
    onExploreItemClicked: OnExploreItemClicked,
    openDrawer: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
   ...
}


@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Qualifier
annotation class DefaultDispatcher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a module declared like this

```
@Module
object DispatcherModule {
    @DefaultDispatcher
    @Provides
    fun providesDefaultDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
   
}
```

Now you create this class in order to use `@DefaultDispatcher` as an annotation

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Qualifier
annotation class DefaultDispatcher
```

For more details, visit [here](https://www.valueof.io/blog/injecting-coroutines-dispatchers-with-dagger)

In [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab/app/src/main/java/androidx/compose/samples/crane/di/DispatchersModule.kt) on your sample project, that you have shared is perfectly written like this.

This means `@DefaultDispatcher` will be used as an annotation, where value will be provided by the `DispatcherModule`